# minikube install failes on OS X

Tags: minikube

I'm downloading minikube on OS X (Catalina 10.15.7) from `releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64` and it fails when run, see below:

```
minikube version
/usr/local/bin/minikube: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/bin/minikube: line 1: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd</Details></Error>'
```

Not sure what key it refers to.

Comment: How did you install the `minikube` (using `brew`, `curl` etc.) ?
Can you provide the entire command you used ?
Could you please verify the size of the `minikube` ?

Comment: First it was installed with brew, but it was 1.15 so I did curl per https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/
ls -l /usr/local/bin/minikube
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me admin  206 Aug 10 07:45 /usr/local/bin/minikube

Comment: This size seems too small for a `minikube`. I think you incorrectly copied the `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64` line, probably without `64` at the end.
Could you please run `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64 && sudo install minikube-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube` again ?

Comment: ouch , that was it, appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused by an invalid URL in the `curl` command. Looking at the error message, my guess is that the `64` was missing at the end.

I've reproduced this error and we can see that the error message is exactly the same as in the question (I'm using Linux so instead of `minikube-darwin-amd64` I used `minikube-linux-amd64`):
**NOTE:** I didn't provide `64` at the end.

```
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   205  100   205    0     0   6029      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6029
$ sudo install minikube-linux-amd /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

The size is too small for the `minikube`:

```
$ ls -lh /usr/local/bin/minikube
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 205 Aug 13 07:30 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

The error message:

```
$ minikube version
/usr/local/bin/minikube: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/bin/minikube: line 1: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd</Details></Error>'
```

Now let's install the `minikube` correctly:

```
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
$ sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

We can see that the real size of the `minikube` is >65M:

```
$ ls -lh /usr/local/bin/minikube
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67M Aug 13 07:32 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

And everything works as expected:

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.22.0
commit: a03fbcf166e6f74ef224d4a63be4277d017bb62e
```